# How do we update a sub-document and add a new field with a value from the same sub-document?

Tags: mongodb, mql

I am running mongo DB version 4.4.5.
I have the following document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "601a597c9932756822d134cb",
    "certificate" : {
        "complete" : true,
        "validFromTimestamp" : NumberLong("1612126800000"),
        "validToTimestamp" : NumberLong("1643576400000")
    }
}
```

I would like to update the record and add another field `nominatedTimestamp` in the certificate sub-document which will have the same value as `certificate.validFromTimestamp`.

I have tried the following MQL query

```
db.collection_name.update({
    "certificate.validFromTimestamp": {
        $exists: true
    },
    "certificate.nominatedTimestamp": {
        $exists: false
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        "certificate.nominatedTimestamp": "$certificate.validFromTimestamp"
    }
})
```

However, the result (as shown below) is that `certificate.nominatedTimestamp` is the  string  `"$certificate.validFromTimestamp"` 
and not the expected value `NumberLong("1612126800000")` :

```
{
    "_id" : "601a597c9932756822d134cb",
    "certificate" : {
        "complete" : true,
        "validFromTimestamp" : NumberLong("1612126800000"),
        "validToTimestamp" : NumberLong("1643576400000"),
        "nominatedTimestamp" : "$certificate.validFromTimestamp"
    }
}
```

How do I make it pick the value of `NumberLong("1612126800000")`?

Comment: you can not use internal field as value in another field, try update with aggregation pipeline just wrap your update part in array bracket like `[ { $set: { "certificate.nominatedTimestamp": "$certificate.validFromTimestamp" } }]`

Comment: Use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: @turivishal  I have tried your suggestion, the output is correct as I expect, however it only displays but does not actually save. I understand this is how actually how aggregation works: it outputs the reshaped document without actually modifying the underlying data.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([ { $match: { "certificate.validFromTimestamp": { $exists: true },"certificate.nominatedTimestamp": { $exists: false } } }, { $set: { "certificate.nominatedTimestamp": "$certificate.validFromTimestamp" } } ])
```

Comment: you don't need to use aggregate function, you just need to change in your update query, only need to add bracket in update part, see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U9OZ6WIKYT5)

Comment: You mean this way

db.collection_name.update({ "certificate.validFromTimestamp": { $exists: true },"certificate.nominatedTimestamp": { $exists: false } },[{ $set: { "certificate.nominatedTimestamp": "$certificate.validFromTimestamp" } } ])

Comment: Thank you for the playground link. This actually solved my issue! really appreciate